# How to avoid memory mapping when loading a numpy file

Tags: python, numpy

Csv file:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.32,0.21,0,0.16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.32
0,0,0,0,0,0,0.17,0,0.04,0,0,0.25,0.03,0.32,0,0.02,0.05,0.03,0.08,0
0.08,0.07,0.09,0.06,0,0,0.21,0.02,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.36,0,0,0
[goes on always 20 columns and x number of rows]
```

I'm saving the array this way:

```
with open(csv_profile) as csv_file:
    array = np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter=",",dtype='str')
npy_profile=open(outfile, "wb")
np.save(npy_profile, array)
```

Which is saved as `u4` instead of `f8` which is what I need.

I noticed this error in the datatype as the output file says

```
<93>NUMPY^A^@v^@{'descr': '<U4', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (680, 20), }
```

Also when I load it:

```
profile_matrix=np.load(npy_profile,"r")
```

the class type is `numpy.memmap` instead of `numpy.ndarray`. How can I avoid this issue?

Both saving it in the correct format and loading it in the correct format.

Comment: The `np.load` docs says, regarding the 2nd argument (if given): "if not None, then memory-map the file, using the given mode ".  You specified 'r'.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know by any chance why it is saving as unsigned integers instead of floats?

Comment: How did you create the array? Is it actually a float array? And how did you notice that it is stored in the wrong format?

Comment: I just added more info

Comment: You can try to add a `.astype(float)` to `array` in your call to `np.save`.

Comment: Or you try not to load it as `str` array from the csv file

Comment: ok ok I will try these out. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed thanks the latter worked!

Comment: If `np.save/load` doesn't do what you expect, check the array (or object) that you give to `save`.  Don't make assumptions about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the [manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) we can see that the second parameter of `numpy.load` is called `mmap_mode` and is set to `"r"` in your code. This enables memory mapping the file:

> A memory-mapped array is kept on disk. However, it can be accessed and sliced like any ndarray. Memory mapping is especially useful for accessing small fragments of large files without reading the entire file into memory.

Memory mapping is normally not an "issue" as you called it, but a feature that enables faster file access and saves memory for large files. When doing memory mapped I/O, your operating system maps parts of the file into the RAM address space of your program. That way the data has not to be copied into RAM. Any changes that are made to the memory mapped numpy array are directly reflected in the file. Because you specified read only access, you probably cannot change values in the array.

If you want to disable memory mapping, you could remove the second argument `"r"` from the call to `numpy.load`, which leads to a fresh copy of the array in RAM, that you can modify without affecting the file.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from Jakob Stark explains what the additional `"r"` argument to `np.load()` does, let me just suggest a simpler and safer usage. To save and load NumPy arrays in the straight-forward way (no memory mapping, etc.), use the most straight-forward syntax:

```py
np.save('filename.npy', array)
array2 = np.load('filename.npy')
```

You don't have to specify the `dtype` or anything, it just does the simplest possible thing, as you are expecting. Also, not manually opening the file prior to calling `np.save()` means that you do not have to worry about closing it again (these acts should generally be written inside a `try`/`except` block, which further adds to the complexity).